# Position Sticky ruined popup z-index

Tags: css, z-index

I have popup and dropdown menu. Popup inside sidebar which has position sticky and dropdown menu inside content div which has position relative; When I open dropdown and after this I open my popup z-index doesn't work as I want.

There is [Codesandbox DEMO](https://ddkntr.csb.app/)

There is Screenshots of the problem:

[image]

The code is really simple

**Html**

```
<div className="container">
    <!-- Aside has position sticky -->
    <aside>
        <button>Open Popup</button>

        <!-- Popup has position fixed -->
        <div className="popup">
            <h2>Popup content</h2>
        </div>
    </aside>

    <!-- Content has position relative -->
    <div className="content">
        <button>Toggle Menu</button>
        
        <!-- Menu has position absolute -->
        <div className="dropdown_menu">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            <a href="#">Link 4</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**There is some styles that I used:**

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 20px;
  
  > aside{
     position: sticky;
     max-width: 200px;
     
     .popup{
       position: fixed;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100vh;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       z-index: 999;
       background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
     }
  }

  .content{
    position: relative;
    flex: 1;
    
    .dropdown_menu{
      position: absolute;
      top: 20px;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, 0);
      background-color: #fff;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is the popup to stay above, simply add `z-index` to your components:

```css
/* sidebar.scss */

.sidebar{
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```css
/* content.scss */

.content {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I knew that my problem is really simple but I really looking for answer about 2 days. Thank you sir for the answer!